# Can't build rmagick on Windows: undefined reference to `GetExceptionInfo'

Tags: ruby, rubygems, imagemagick, installation, rmagick

When I try **gem install rmagick**, I get many errors like

       **undefined reference to `GetExceptionInfo'**

There are also undefined references to

> AverageImages DestroyConstitute GetExceptionInfo MapImage MapImages
>   MedianFilterImage RadialBlurImage RadialBlurImageChannel RecolorImage
>   ReduceNoiseImage

These functions all appear to be in CORE_RL_magick_.lib but I can't find any combination of --with-opt-lib or --with-opt-dir or environment variables like LDFLAGS or CFLAGS or LIBRARY_PATH or LD_LIBRARY_PATH that allows "linking shared-object RMagick2.so" to succeed - or that make any difference at all.

Where is this function defined? How can I bring it in to the link (ld) step?

I'm running
   ImageMagick 6.7.7-8 Q8

   DevKit-tdm-32-4.5.2-20111229-1559-sfx.exe (gcc 4.5.2)

Thanks for any ideas.

---

Some references:

- http://codeofalice.com/code/installing-rmagick-on-windows-7/
- https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick/wiki/Installing-on-Windows
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEWAVlNCKhg
- [rmagick not building on windows 7 undefined reference errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7151030) - undefined reference
  errors
- [Facing issues with rmagic gem while installing in Windows machine and it is for Rails 3 application.. ruby version 1.8.7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4469042) - issues building
- [rmagick installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561386) - more issues
- [Can't install rmagick due to some gem exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23090992) - gen exception
- [how do you get rmagick to work on windows 7 64-bit with rails 3.1 and carrierwave?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232962)

Comment: Along the way I did "gem update --system" (to 2.4.2) which created other make errors. "gem update --system 2.0.0" again allows me to build native extensions... but not rmagick.

Comment: CORE_RL_magick_.lib for ImageMagick 6778, 6803, and 6895 all export _GetExceptionInfo (with one leading underscore) but ld fails with "undefined reference to `GetExceptionInfo'" (no underscore). Is this a problem with _stdcall decoration? Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this will help someone some day.

I got past this by upgrading to Ruby 2.0.0p481 32-bit (current as of this note). Next I installed the 32-bit DevKit. I also installed ImageMagick 6.7.7-8 (though other versions might work) and placed it first in my PATH.

With that,

> gem install rmagick --platform=ruby -- --with-opt-dir=c:\Tools\ImageMagick

ran fine and installed rmagick 2.13.2.

Comment: Worked for me also in the combination rmagick 2.13.4, ImageMagick-6.9.0-10 and ruby 2.1.5 (64bit). In addition I needed the parameter LD_LIBRARY_PATH (see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4451213/ruby-1-9-2-how-to-install-rmagick-on-windows)